Potential Issues with Using Different Top Level Domains for From Address and Link/Images Branding
I'm managing a setup in SFMC with the following configuration:

We have a Sender Authentication Package (SAP) configured for the
subdomain e.xyz.com in one Child Business Unit (BU).

We want to share this SAP with another Child BU so that our
CloudPages, tracking links, and images all use the same domain
(e.xyz.com), and to avoid having to go through the IP warmup process
again with a new dedicated IP.

However, in the second BU, we want to send emails from addresses like
support@e.xyz.arg (with a .arg TLD), as this matches the business
operations in that region.


Challenges and Questions:

What issues might arise from sending emails with a From Address
using .arg while the tracking links and images are branded with the
.com subdomain due to the shared SAP?
Could this mismatch between the From Address (.arg) and the branded
links (.com) affect deliverability, trust, or trigger spam filters?
Are there best practices for managing branding consistency across
different TLDs in SFMC without purchasing a separate SAP for the
.arg domain?


There is nothing wrong with using different SAP and Private Domain for sending. You will need to ask Salesforce support to enable multi-bounce domain feature, as otherwise your DMARC will fail.
Let’s assume your are sending from e.xyz.com, which is your SAP today:
SAP domain populates the bounce domain: bounce.e.xyz.com
Your new private domain populates the from domain: e.xyz.arg
DMARC fails because example.com does not equal e.xyz.arg
What would work:

SAP domain populates the bounce domain: bounce.e.xyz.com
Private domain populates an alternative from domain, with another subdomain: hello.xyz.com

DMARC passes because in both cases they use the domain xyz.com
So in the past this was only safe if all domains involved were part of the same domain name – or if you did not implement DMARC on those domains.
There is a new(ish) feature called multi-bounce domain. When that is enabled, the system will always change the bounce domain setting to be bounce.[from domain] – like this:

From domain: e.xyz.arg
Bounce domain auto-set to: bounce.e.xyz.arg

Hence you can use a PD different from your SAP domain. Multi bounce is enabled upon request, by submitting a support case requesting help setting up multi-bounce domain support for your new private domain.
I believe a full IP warmup on the new domain is not needed - especially if you will only send a fraction of your volume there. E.g. you send 300.000 emails per month from e.xyz.com and will start sending 10.000 from e.xyz.arg - this will work fine. If you expect to send more than half of your total volume from your new domain, I will recommend to ramp up the volume slowly over the first 4 weeks.

what will happen if I don't set this multi bounce feature? Why multi bounce is the one that should be set, and not click or image.

As I explained, @teddy23 your DMARC will fail. In simple terms, DMARC failures mean your emails aren't passing the security checks that DMARC enforces, and as a result, they're getting blocked or rejected by the recipient's domain. The bounce domain needs to be aligned to your sender domain (being your new private domain) and not your SAP domain, which is default bounce domain.

Thank you Lukas. Could you please tell me if I have SAP shared from other BU, do I need to buy a private domain in SFMC if I have a webpage on a xyz.arg (so I bought it but not through SFMC)? If I want to have a From Email Address e.g. marketing.e.xyz.arg? Or maybe I need to pay SFMC to be able to use my domain in SFMC?
If I have a SAP can I have any number of private domains in SFMC and I don't have to pay for it?

@teddy23 you should not purchase additional domains. Private Domain is a SKU you purchase from Salesforce, which will make them configure DNS settings for e.xyz.arg, allowing you to use it as a sender domain. You can read more about Private Domains on Salesforce Marketing Cloud here

Thank you. I have 2 more questions. I will be grateful if you could respond:


Do we need to buy this SKU? Why can't we configure SPF, DKIM and DMARC on our own and we need to delegate it to SF?


I read on the page you linkedin that it is possible to ask SF to provide SSL for our private domain, but those ssl are also a part of SAP, right?



@teddy23 1: yes you do need to buy this SKU. Why? SF needs to do configuration of this domain in their end. They will provide you the SPF, DKIM and DMARC values to put in your DNS zone, even if you self-host. Why should it cost you money for this SKU? Well - I'm not the one behind SF product strategy :-) 2: You don't need SSL if you only will be using this PD for sends - it will be useful if you also will be using same PD for Cloud Pages. And SSLs are never part of SAP package. They always are to be purchased separately.

Thanks! Is it required to buy a SKU for each subdomain? Let's say I have xyz.arg private domain in SFMC. Can I create as many subdomains as I want? Or do I need to have a SKU for each subdomain and delegate it to SF? Many thanks for the answer!

@teddy23 you will need one PD per subdomain (i.e. 1 for abc.xyz.arg and another for def.xyz.arg)



What issues might arise from sending emails with a From Address using
.arg while the tracking links and images are branded with the .com
subdomain due to the shared SAP?


-> you are changing the sender domain.
Your new domain is "cold", and some ESPs consider domain more than IP for reputation. You might be looking at another (IP) Warming even though you don't touch the IP. IP is in brackets as you are technically warming your sendout configuration of IP and domain, not your IP.


Could this mismatch between the From Address (.arg) and the branded
links (.com) affect deliverability, trust, or trigger spam filters?


Where your links point is typically not a factor in this. Your links should be https and should work, that matters. You can easily check this from any org by sending an email to e.g. mail-tester.com and investigate a) what is considered for the spam score, and b) observe that your link targets are not being considered.
example below, under all of these categories you'll see more details on the individual factors, and you might be surprised by things like "text-to-image ratio" etc.



Are there best practices for managing branding consistency across
different TLDs in SFMC without purchasing a separate SAP for the .arg
domain?


SAP does full branding with link etc. domains.
Private Domains (PDs) each only brand the sender domain OR a cloud page domain. SAP is 1 per BU, PD is n per BU. Make of this what you will.
In my personal opinion setting up multiple top level domains just for branding sounds like overkill, if you have a reasonably generic domain to start with.
Just play with the sender name, make it argentina@genericsubdomain.domain.com and never bother with any of the risk, hassle around warming etc.

"SAP is 1 per BU, PD is n per BU" but it's possible to share same sap across different BU? Basically that's my case. I will share SAP from one BU to another where I will have different private domain .arg instead of .com. So in the second BU, I will have the ip reputation warmed in the first BU.

Sharing IP address is independent from Sharing SAPs. Both is possible. Just share the IP, that way you do profit from existing IP reputation without even touching SAP. Regardless: By sending from a different domain - no matter how you set it up, PD or SAP - you can still get negative effects at domain focused ESPs, if that domain is completely cold and you start at high volumes.

"In my personal opinion setting up multiple top level domains just for branding sounds like overkill, if you have a reasonably generic domain to start with.". Why do you think that? I have domain with SAP on one BU with TLD .com, so I need .arg and .xyz for other countries (business units).

...because of the work you'll put into authentication etc. for a branding detail, as laid out. This is not a brand strategy website, I am giving you the "technical" perspective. I am not advocating brand-less or -agnostic sendouts, I am saying you can make your life easier by sticking to one branded authenticated .com domain and playing with the sender email before the @, not after for your multi-country setup.
